# OpenIddict MVC core 2.0 and JWT on resource server API

Tags: .net, api, asp.net-core-mvc, jwt, openiddict

I have been setting up an OpenIdDict authserver for use with our existing mvc core 2.0 web application. I am using code flow and made a test mvc webapp resource server before implementing OpenIdConnect part on our production application(s).

Everything seems to be working as intended and I can log in and access my resources.

I need to get api bearer authentication working under new auth architecture for my rest clients. Api is placed on the same resource server.

I have set up my OpenIddict for JWT using:

```
            options.AllowPasswordFlow();
            options.UseJsonWebTokens();
            options.AddSigningKey(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("TokenAuthentication:SecretKey").Value)));
```

...added JwtBearer

```
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultOutboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:17004/";
                options.Audience = "MyAudience";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject,
                    RoleClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("TokenAuthentication:SecretKey").Value))
                };
            });
```

...and added code in AuthorizationController.Exchange for handling password flow token requests.

On my resource server Startup.cs i have added AddOpenIdConnect and added signingKey (same key as on my auth server).

```
            options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
            options.AuthenticationMethod = OpenIdConnectRedirectBehavior.RedirectGet;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("TokenAuthentication:SecretKey").Value))
            };
            options.Authority = "http://localhost:17004/";
```

After setting this up my resource server can still authenticate and everything is working and I can use a restclient to obtain a jwt token from my auth server but when trying to access my api on resource server it fails because there is no validator for bearer scheme.

If I add call to call AddBearerToken on resource server with the same signingKey in TokenValidationParameters it actually works. The challenge is sucessful and I have access to my resources.

However I suspect my setup is far from corrrect since I can see that, when calling my api, validation of my token is happening on resource server so I am left with 2 questions.

1. Is it possible to have the JwtBearer middleware forward the validation to my auth server? (can openidConnect handle it?)
2. Is it possible to make my resource server forward/passthru token issue requests too my auth server so my rest api client wont have to deal with 2 servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have the JwtBearer middleware forward the validation to my auth server? (can openidConnect handle it?)

The JWT bearer middleware always performs local validation using the signing key retrieved from OpenIddict's configuration endpoint. You have no way to force it to delegate this task to OpenIddict.

> Is it possible to make my resource server forward/passthru token issue requests too my auth server so my rest api client wont have to deal with 2 servers?

If you want to delegate the token validation part to your authorization server, then don't use the JWT middleware. Instead, enable introspection in the OpenIddict options, create a new confidential client application registration and use the [aspnet-contrib introspection middleware](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Introspection), that will use backchannel HTTP calls to validate the incoming tokens.

Comment: After I added a certificate to OpenIddict auth server the jwks worked and the resource server side can get the key from that and I understand the validation will happen on resource server which is fine (It was the multiple registration of signingkeys that worried me). But my REST client app still need to contact auth server directly for initial token issuing. Can I make that happen via my resource server?

Comment: ...also you mentioned that for my case I should not be using OpenIdConnect on my resource server. Can you provide an example of how to set up resource server using only JwtBearer? (After removing openidconnect the challenge in auth.controller fails because no handler exists for openidconnect scheme. If I change the scheme to "Bearer" it never contacts auth server and just give 401.)

Comment: I ended up making a small discovery method on my resource server telling my REST client where to find authority and then use .well-known/openid-configuration on auth server for finding token endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

JWT is a token format and required for OpenIdConnect. You can use any token format with Oauth2 including JWT. So you don't need to skip the JWT.

Comment: I think i have a problem understanding some of the basics as the words you write have no meaning to me. I have spent a lot of time trying to figure out what is part of which flow and what technology is used where and I'm totally lost between finding out how to configure mvc core 2.0 for it and how oid should be implemented to work.

Comment: I have  written an article on this and it has overview of these concepts. Link is here - https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/microservices-security-openid-connect-manish-singh

Comment: Good article. I have also found out some more about my mvc setup and edited my question since I'm now able to ask the right ones.